# C# - Public Global connection to SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection

I am new to C# and I started studying just yesterday.

I have created class to connect to SQL Server:

```
namespace Exchange_Ofiice.Classes
{
    public class sqlConn
    {
        public void connectionMethod()
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=ID;password=PASS;server=SERVER;database=DB;");
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Невозможно подключиться к Базе данных. Пожалуйста обратитесь к программистам!", "Ошибка подключения к Базе данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

and another class for user authentification:

```
namespace Exchange_Ofiice.Classes
{
    public class auth:sqlConn
    {

        public void authMethod() 
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", myConnection);                          
        }

    }
}
```

How to get (use) SQL connection result (`myConnection`) in second class?

P.S. line `SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", myConnection);` does not work.

P.S.S. Sorry, if I have mistake, my english is not perfect.

Comment: It's best to share the connection *string* around the application, but don't do it with the connection. Wherever you need a connection, you should create a new one, `Open` it, use it for the current piece of work, and `Close` it (or, equivalently, have it inside a `using` block). Don't try to share connection objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. So you have the SQLConnection in the class and not in the function.
If you declare something in a function it will only be accessible in that function.

```
 public class sqlConn
{
    public SqlConnection myConnection;
    public void connectionMethod()
    {
        myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=ID;password=PASS;server=SERVER;database=DB;");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Невозможно подключиться к Базе данных. Пожалуйста обратитесь к программистам!", "Ошибка подключения к Базе данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh you might want to consider making the SQLConnection private

```
private SqlConnection myConnection;
```

And then make a function to retrieve the value.

```
   public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return myConnection;
    }
```

And in the other class it will be:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", GetConnection());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, connection should be  public field of your class, not function variable. And secondly, you're closing your connection in finally, so you have no chance to make it working later.

```
public class sqlConn
{ 
        public SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=ID;password=PASS;server=SERVER;database=DB;");

        public void connectionMethod()
        {          
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Here goes error handling...
            }                 
    }
}
```

And, surely, in your authMethod you should make checks for connection state, to prevent exceptions, if connection was not initialized.

Also, as good practice, make sure you're implementing **IDisposable** interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)  for your connection class, otherwise you might have some troubles later.